# Github "Branch name pattern" negation

Tags: regex, github

On Github, when you go to branch settings and create a "Branch protection rule", how do I specify any branch other than 'master'? I've tried a bunch of regex-like expressions, but none seem to work :(

Comment: I'm not sure but give this a try `{m,[^m]*,ma,m[^a]*,mas,ma[^s]*,mast,mas[^t]*,maste,mast[^e]*,maste[^r]*}`

Comment: @revo "Rule is invalid" :(

Comment: Github’s fnmatch implementation seems limited. Anyone who figured it out?

Comment: I've opened a community feedback post asking for [regex  as a new feature](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/53523)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

GitHub uses `fnmatch` to match against any pattern provided to find out the branches to which the rule applies for branch protection.

There isn't an exact `fnmatch` pattern for GitHub yet which can resolve to precisely anything other than **master**, but the pattern closest to it would be:

```
*[!master]*
```

But this would also exclude branches with only `m`,`a`,`s`,`t`,`e`,`r` or branches with only a combination of those letters.

Check out more details on the above on [GitHub help](https://help.github.com/en/articles/configuring-protected-branches) and the [fnmatch documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/File.html#method-c-fnmatch)

Comment: Hey @MadhuBhat, `fnmatch` page never talks about `[!...]` syntax. Would you mind telling where is it come from?

Comment: @revo the documentation doesn't provide an example for this exact case, but I derived it out myself of the examples given. With the syntaxes for `*c*`, `[set]` and `! or ^` being negation operators.

Comment: I found in docs that `!` behaves the same as `^` for negating a character class. It means `[!master]` doesn't mean **not `master`** but it means **neither `m`, `a`, `s`, `t`, `e` nor `r`**.

Comment: This is the proper way to setup GitHub branch rules: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61421938/135079

Comment: gitlab is not using fnmatch for protected branches, sadly, but a regex and they escape the rule so the it supports only `*` in a fnmatch way: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/app/models/ref_matcher.rb#L38-45

Answer (score 36):

What you can do is create a rule with:

```
master
```

and then create another rule (after the first one) with:

```
**/**
```

Then this second one will apply to all branches except master because master is covered by a previous rule:

[image]

Comment: Perfect workaround !!

Comment: How to reorder existing rules?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by creating six separate rules:

```
[!m]*
m[!a]*
ma[!s]*
mas[!t]*
mast[!e]*
maste[!r]*
```

[image: branch protection rules]

Comment: Concrete example of how switching to `main` as the default branch would make life simpler. +1 for a clever solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the following branch name pattern:

```
[!m][!a][!s][!t][!e][!r]
```

This pattern will capture **ALL** other branches that are **NOT** named "master".

If you use the 6 separate rules, found in a previous reply, you will have 6 different rules to manage and not be enforcing what you intended.

Answer (score -1):

Github branch name patterns are based on "fnmatch", not in regex. In order to match all the branch names that contain "master" keyword, we used the pattern below.

```
**/master
```

Answer (score -13):

You can use Negative Lookahead to assert that the string "master" does not match:

```
^((?!^master$).)*$
```

You can test this regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/AxRD5I/1)

Comment: Nope. Message given: "Rule is invalid" for `^((?!^master$).)*$`

Comment: It seems like github's branch protection rules only supports wildcards and not regular expressions

Comment: Github rules are base in fnmatch, not in regex